# Bash - execute commands in opened a program

Tags: bash

Code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
X=$(pgrep weechat)
re='^[0-9]+$'

if [[ $X =~ $re ]] ; then
    echo "process '$X' killed"
    `kill -9 $X`
else
    echo "no running weechat sessions"
fi

weechat
sleep .1
echo "/connect secure"
```

The last "echo" needs to write "/connect secure" and hit enter inside of the weechat program

How do you recommend I do this?

Comment: well, here is a couple examples https://weechat.org/scripts/

Answer (score 0):

According to [WeeChat user’s guide](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/weechat-doc/html/weechat_user.en.html) there is a FIFO created that accepts commands "if option `plugins.var.fifo.fifo` is enabled, it is by default".

Simply grab the PID of the weechat process (in order to find the FIFO file):

```
weechat &
weechat_pid=$!
printf '%s\n' "/connect secure" >~/.weechat/weechat_fifo_${weechat_pid}
```

I'd also suggest a change to your `kill` command as listed; doing this:

> `kill -9 $X`

attempts to execute a command that is the stdout resulting from the kill command. You're simply trying to kill the process, so just run the kill command:

```
kill -9 "$X"
```

or since you're already relying on pgrep, just use pkill:

```
pkill -9 "$X"
```

and since you just seem to be checking whether pgrep found a PID or not, just check it's return code:

```
pgrep weechat >/dev/null && pkill weechat
```